# Automatically append text to a \newtcolorbox environment

Tags: tcolorbox

I'd like a way to style a `tcolorbox` generated environment such that some arbitrary text is always append to its body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `after upper` option

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mytcolorbox}{
         after upper={\ and this  text is added every time}
     }
\begin{document}
\begin{mytcolorbox}
The body text
\end{mytcolorbox}
\end{document}
```